# echo is not working in my php-gdlibrary page

Tags: php, header, echo, gdlib

i am trying to create an ellipse using php gd library; also i want to display something under the ellipse. but the usual echo will not work with this. somebody please help me to find the reason and suggest a solution.

this is my php code

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
$handle = imagecreate(100, 100);
$background = imagecolorallocate($handle, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($handle, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($handle, 0, 255, 0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($handle, 0, 0, 255);
for ($i = 60; $i > 50; $i--)
{
imagefilledarc($handle, 50, $i, 100, 50, 0, 90, $darkred, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($handle, 50, $i, 100, 50, 90, 360 , $darkblue, IMG_ARC_PIE);
}
imagefilledarc($handle, 50, 50, 100, 50, 0, 90, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($handle, 50, 50, 100, 50, 90, 225 , $blue, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($handle, 50, 50, 100, 50, 225, 360 , $green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagepng($handle);
```

thanks in advance

tismon

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't work.
Basic HTML knowledge is necessary before gdlibrary exercises.

Open any HTML page with an image and a text, and see, how it works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output text to an image you have to use the image functions that do just that, so your first stop should be the PHP reference.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

There you will find the following that allow you to output text to images :
[imagefttext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php), [imagepstext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepstext.php), [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Check out the examples to see how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your elipse, and some additional text (or HTML) then you need to do the following...

```
<img src="your-script-that-makes-an-elipse.php" alt="Elipse">
<p>This is an elipse.</p>
```

Essentially, you use your PHP-generated image as the source of an HTML image tag. You can also use your normal "echo" statements in this page.

```
<img src="your-script-that-makes-an-elipse.php" alt="Elipse">
<p><?php echo $ElipseDescription; ?></p>
```

You can see this in action if you view the source of the preview images here - the smaller images are created by a PHP script using GD (the script also handles caching of preview images to speed things up):

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Gallery/Gallery/Animals/